# How to push data to create pie chart - chart js

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have data from SQL in json code file (checked in Fiddler)

> {"d":[{"__type":"Dashboards.Employee","name":"Test
>   Hen","turnover":"1500000,0000","color":"#231F20"},{"__type":"Dashboards.Employee","name":"Test
>   Bai","turnover":"130000,0000","color":"#FFC200"}]}

but i dont know, how to push them  correctly in order to create pie chart

my ajax/javascript is here:

```
  $.ajax({
                   url: 'HelloService.asmx/GetEmployeeDetail',
                   contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                   data: JSON.stringify({ month: number }),
                   dataType: 'json',
                   method: 'post',                     
                   success: OnSuccess_,
                   error: OnErrorCall_
               });

               function OnSuccess_(response) {


                   var aData = response.d;
                   var arr = [];
                   //var ctx = document.getElementById('pele').getContext('2d');
                   $.each(aData, function (inx, val) {
                       var obj = {};
                       obj.label = val.name;
                       obj.value = val.turnover;
                       obj.color = val.color;
                       arr.push(obj);
                   });
                   var ctx = $("#pele").get(0).getContext("2d");
                   var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(arr);}


                   function OnErrorCall_(response) {
                   console.log(error);
                     }

                 });

             });
```

Am I missing something?

If i use static values (value, label, color) pie chart works without problem.
Thank you

Comment: Do you get any error? Your code snippet looks wrong (last 3 lines). What version of ChartJS do you use?

Comment: Hi, i didnt get error :( ...... Version: 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following FiddleJS for you: https://jsfiddle.net/cukyrh5h/1/

You need to replace the URL of the Ajax call with yours of course. You had some wrong syntax (too much braches in the end of your Snippet) and the API you were using was not working with ChartJS 2.4 anymore.

The code looks like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/echo/json/",
    data:data,
    type:"POST",
    success:OnSuccess_
});

function OnSuccess_(response) {
  var aData = response.d;
  var data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: []
    }]
  };

  $.each(aData, function (inx, val) {
    data.labels.push(val.name);
    data.datasets[0].data.push(val.turnover);
    data.datasets[0].backgroundColor.push(val.color);
  });

  var ctx = $("#pele").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data
  });
}

function OnErrorCall_(response) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Looks it works! ... but question .... you have declared variable response .... is there any way how to get response without declaration?  - in my case i see just name( labels without  chart) - because of my data declaration : data: JSON.stringify({ month: number }),

Comment: Sure, you have to adjust the Ajax Request to yours from above. The thing I used is a special helper from JSFiddle to help simulate Ajax Request (it sends back the data I send via POST). Simply remove the response I declared, adjust the URL, and send your data instead of my reponse.

Comment: Hi Marc, i dont know why, i can see just  labels  - Test Hen Test Bai which are  cross out .... why is it so ?

Comment: Looks like main problem is my data in ajax ..... i have here data: JSON.stringify({ month: number}), - iam passing value from drop down list to stored procedure as parameter

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found problem, why i cant see my Chart. Maybe it will be useful for another members. Data in Database (turnover was daclared as money, i changed it to int .... and it works)